# Check if NSNumber is fraction

Tags: objective-c, ios, macos, nsnumber

What is the best way of checking if a `NSNumber` is a fraction?

```
NumberIsFraction(@(0)); // NO;
NumberIsFraction(@(0.5)); // YES;
NumberIsFraction(@(1.0)); // NO;
```

"Best" in terms of border case handling and performance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Avoiding conversions to types with a smaller domain:

```
BOOL NumberIsFraction(NSNumber *number) {
    double dValue = [number doubleValue];
    if (dValue < 0.0)
        return (dValue != ceil(dValue));
    else
        return (dValue != floor(dValue));
}
```

Comment: I think those should be `!=`? `NumberIsFraction(@(0.0f))` would return `YES`, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 8):

The solutions from Jonathan, hpique, and prashant all have the same bug: they involve casting `NSNumber` to fixed-precision types (variously `double`, `long long`, etc.), which breaks if the value is a very large `NSDecimalNumber`. For example, the accepted answer fails on `NSDecimalNumber(string: "1000000000000000.1")`.

A more correct implementation (as an extension, in Swift):

```
extension NSNumber {
    var isFraction: Bool {
        var decimal = decimalValue, decimalRounded = decimal
        NSDecimalRound(&decimalRounded, &decimal, 0, .down)
        return NSDecimalNumber(decimal: decimalRounded) != self
    }
}
```

Or in Objective-C, as a global function:

```
BOOL NumberIsFraction(NSNumber *number) {
    NSDecimal rounded = number.decimalValue;
    NSDecimalRound(&rounded, &rounded, 0, NSRoundDown);
    return ![number isEqualToNumber:
        [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithDecimal:rounded]];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm currently using:

```
BOOL NumberIsFraction(NSNumber* number) {
    return ![number isEqualToNumber:@(number.longLongValue)];
}
```

Comment: That will work for many integers, but very large or very negative integers will break during conversion to/from `long long`.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(BOOL) NumberIsFraction: (NSNumber*)number
{
   NSLog(@"%0.16g",number.doubleValue);
   NSLog(@"%d", number.intValue);
   double diff = number.doubleValue - number.intValue;
   if (diff>0)
     return YES;
   else return NO;
}
```